# What is a Sink in springframework.cloud.stream.messaging package?

Tags: kafka-consumer-api, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

The application i am running, would behave as a consumer in kafka streams. I have kafka messaging configured via spring's stream.

How to figure out whether its consuming from the right topic?

Also whats is SINK in springframework.cloud.stream.messaging package? What roles does it play. How to configure it. What is Sink.INPUT?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I follow your question since you did not provide any examples. Initially you're stating that you have configured your application as spring-cloud-stream application, but then you're asking questions about Sink that leads me to believe that you have not actually done what you stated, so I am confused.

What I would suggest is to look at spring-cloud-stream samples - https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-samples

Also, this section of the documentation explains the concept of the Source, Processor and Sink - https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream/2.2.1.RELEASE/spring-cloud-stream.html#_destination_bindings

Finally, note that we are moving toward a simpler configuration model with functional approach. You can get more information from [this blog](https://spring.io/blog/2019/10/14/spring-cloud-stream-demystified-and-simplified) which also provides links to get more details

Comment: We're moving away from all annotation-based programming model and while we will support what we have for some time, given that you're starting with spring-cloud-stream, I am wondering why you still insist on using something for which there is a significantly simpler alternative?